# Remove ppa from previous Ubuntu versions

Tags: apt, ppa

As the title, is there any way to automatically identify and remove ppa residual of previous release?
I have upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 from 13.04 and my /etc/apt/sources.list.d directory contains a lot of raring ppa.

E.g.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  248 set  8 12:10 jd-team-jdownloader-raring.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  248 apr 26 21:12 jd-team-jdownloader-raring.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  248 set  8 12:10 jd-team-jdownloader-raring.list.save
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can PPAs be removed?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed)

Comment: I think the author knows how to remove them, and rather wants to know what the suffixes mean.

Comment: @Takkat Yep, I already know how to remove PPAs manually.

Comment: @Ben Yes, you're right. The problem is that I have a lot of reference to raring PPAs and I want to remove all them in a single shot. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if this is the right way to do this, but it works for me.
N.B.: I only had raring ppa

`$>sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*-raring.list`